# Disable Session State Access when using an HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a class that uses IHTTPHandler and does not implement **IRequiresSessionState** or **IReadOnlySessionState**.  I still see it accessing our Session provider which is causing excessive usage.

**Stack Trace:**
    HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal =>
    HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest =>
    ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps =>
    HttpApplication.ExecuteStep =>
    AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute =>
    SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState =>
    SessionStateProvider.ResetItemTimeout =>
    SessionStateItem.Save

Is there a way to tell the HttpHandler to not use Session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tough to find any formal documentation on this issue, but it looks like the answer is no. Even if you don't implement `IRequiresSessionState` or `IReadOnlySessionState`, if you are using the SQL Server Session provider you'll still see a call to the `TempResetTimeout` procedure. At least that's what I've found from my testing.

If you really want to avoid session without using a separate web application with Session entirely disabled, you could create an `HttpModule`, instead of using an `HttpHandler`. It's not an ideal approach, but in my testing it did work.

Basically, you do what you need to using the `BeginRequest` event handler and complete the request in `BeginRequest` (i.e., by calling `context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`). If you spy the database using SQL Profiler you'll see that no Session database calls are made.

I wish I had a better answer, but that seems to be the way it works (in ASP.NET 4.0 anyway).

Comment: That link is dead unfortunately